# How to set dynamic connection string in from action filter for mongodb asp.net core

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, http-headers, connection-string, action-filter

I have a parent class for dataaccess layer which reads connection string from sharedappsettings. For each request i want to set connection string dynamically from may be action filter based on header parameter. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For setting connection string with Request header, you could try `IHttpContextAccessor` in `DbContext` like

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly HttpContext httpContext;
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connection = httpContext.Request.Headers["Connectionstring"];
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
    }       
}
```